# Ubuntu 20.04 myslq-server-8 mysqld fails with any other than bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Tags: mysql

As per subject.
I wanted to limit the servers listening to local lan in 192.168.1.0/29 by
bind-address = 192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3

but this always leads to

```
"Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"
```

As I understood, one should be able to limit the accepted addresses by a list?

Comment: Do you notice anything in particular that's different between `192.168.1.1`, `192.168.1.2`, `192.168.1.3` and the value `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` that you are apparently trying to connect to?

Comment: @andrewe-henle 
Not sure what you are after here...
How to check the value of the socket?
Now that I have the bind address on the 0.0.0.0:

    sudo find / -type s | grep sql

I get:
    
    /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    /run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting bind_address=0.0.0.0 , but limiting connections to mysql port from local net only by firewall rules:

sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 3306